# Gnuradio companion - Unable to select an appropriate editor to edit python code block

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm using gnuradio companion 3.10.9.2 on Win 10 and are unable to select an appropriate text editor for modifying an embedded python block.
When I double click on the proto embedded block, I'm offered a "Open in Editor" option which brings up "Doxillion.exe" which I don't want or a "Choose Editor" option. This show the default editor application once more but nothing else. There is a "View All Applications" option shown at the bottom. The "View All Applications" option however brings up a list of random applications from my computer, but none are suitable for editing text. I do have notebook++ installed which would be my choice, but it's not offered.

Following another post I have seen here, I have tried changing the editor in

C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming.gnuradio\config.conf as follows

```
[grc]
canvas_default_size = 1280, 1024
canvas_font_size = 8
default_flow_graph = 
editor = C:\Applications\Notepad++.exe
enabled_components = testing-support;python-support;man-pages;gnuradio-runtime;gr-ctrlport;gnuradio-    companion;JSON/YAML config blocks;gr-blocks;gr-fec;gr-fft;gr-filter;gr-analog;gr-digital;gr-dtv;gr-audio;* portaudio;* windows;gr-channels;gr-pdu;gr-iio;* libad9361;gr-qtgui;gr-trellis;gr-uhd;gr-uhd UHD 4.0 RFNoC;gr-utils;gr_modtool;gr_blocktool;gr-video-sdl;gr-vocoder;* codec2;* freedv;gr-wavelet;gr-zeromq;gr-    network;gr-soapy
local_blocks_path = 
xterm_executable = xterm
```

and have also tried adding

```
[grc]
editor = C:\Applications\Notepad++.exe`
```

to the C:\Users\Steve.gnuradio\grc.conf file as I saw suggested in another post.

In any event, neither of the above result in Notepad++ executing when attempting to edit a Python block.
I'm rather at my wits end here and can't find any way to edit an embedded Python block, so any suggestions as to what I could next would be welcome. (BTW - Notepad++ may not be installed in the default place, but it is perfectly functional)

I note various persons complaining that there manually selected editor gets ignored every time they restart gnuradio companion, but I can't even select an editor in the first instance. I have two Win10 computers with exactly the same problem.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: 1. try removing the spaces around `=`

Comment: 2. Running `C:\Applications\Notepad++.exe` does work, right? If in doubt, press windowskey + r, and paste in `C:\Applications\Notepad++.exe`.

Comment: Many thanks Marcus. Removing the spaces didn't do anything, but the windowskey ^R didn't work which put me on the right track. All good now.

Comment: Then please either post a answer to your question (**don't** edit the question to say it's solved, instead actually post an answer), or delete the question to "clean up the interwebs", so that when someone searches the internet doesn't get confused

Answer (score 1):

In

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming.gnuradio\config.conf as follows

Edit the entry in the [grc] section as follows

```
[grc]
...
...
...
editor = [Full path name of desired executable].exe
...
```

And also in file C:\Users[user].gnuradio\grc.conf add the entry if not found

```
[grc]
editor = [Full path name of desired executable].exe
```